# Angular 5 error on keyup.enter

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm upgrading from angular 4.4 to 5.2

The application runs ok but on one screen i get an error

> TableComponent.html:27 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'onAndCancel' of null
>       at platform-browser.es5.js:3251
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:142)
>       at NgZone.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js:4708)
>       at KeyEventsPlugin.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-notify-popup/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.KeyEventsPlugin.addEventListener (platform-browser.es5.js:3250)
>       at EventManager.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-notify-popup/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.EventManager.addEventListener (platform-browser.es5.js:2395)
>       at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-notify-popup/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.listen (platform-browser.es5.js:2914)
>       at BaseAnimationRenderer.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-notify-popup/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.listen (animations.es5.js:491)
>       at DebugRenderer2.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.listen (core.js:15475)
>       at listenToElementOutputs (core.js:10618)

I tracked the error down to one line of code

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of data; let rowIndex = index"
      ...
      (keyup.enter)="onRowAction(row)"
```

if i change it to (keyup) the error disappears and the app works as expected (but the function it triggered by any key)

Did something change in angular with regards to binding to a single key?

Comment: Can you paste the code under `onRowAction(row)`

Comment: Max's suggestion below would do the job, but `(keyup.enter)` should work and is a much nicer solution as it avoids all those additional event triggers. I'd suggest you try to replicate this behaviour in a plunkr example - it could be that you've found a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would use (keyup)="onRowAction(row, $event)" and then check to see if the correct key was pressed inside of onRowAction().

```
onRowAction(row: any, event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Do stuffz.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in testing this, so for what its worth here are two plunks using Angular 5.2, which test this:

1. `(keyup.enter)` on an input element inside a repeating `<tr>`
   https://plnkr.co/edit/iTbp4oGD4gNb4IVloewF?p=preview
2. `(keyup.enter)` on a repeating `<tr>`, which is still triggered for child DOM elements
   https://plnkr.co/edit/1AICpyAH4NlXTG9M88zC?p=preview

So to answer the question: no, it hasnt been changed and still works. The issue you're encountering must be specific to your code.